# input parameter - cannot be interpreted as an index

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, graph, arguments

I want to build a simple unoriented graph class that has a variable number of vertices and is represented as a adjacency matrix. The problem is that I get the error:

```
File "/home/codrinz/PycharmProjects/lab3ai/Graph.py", line 8, in __init__
self.matrix = np.zeros(s)
TypeError: object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

when I want to build the null matrix. The code is:

```
import numpy as np

class Graph:

def __init__(self,noOfNodes):
    self.size = noOfNodes
    s = (noOfNodes,noOfNodes)
    self.matrix = np.zeros(s)

def isTriangle(self,v1,v2,v3):
    if self.matrix[v1][v2] == 0:
        return False
    if self.matrix[v2][v3] == 0:
        return False
    if self.matrix[v3][v1] == 0:
        return False
    return True

def size(self):
    return self.size

def addEdge(self,v1,v2):
    self.matrix[v1][v2] = 1
    self.matrix[v2][v1] = 1
```

Comment: what is `noOfNodes` set with??

Comment: Post the code that actually throws the error, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was doing:

```
newGraph = Graph(graph)
```

graph being also received as a parameter instead of the noOfVertices.